# need php curl for terminal

Tags: php, curl, terminal

I have the following php curl command:

```
// GET TOKEN
$ch = curl_init('https://api.meinbuero.de/openapi/auth/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $wisoApiKey . ":" . $wisoSecretApiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('ownershipId' => $wisoOwnershipId)) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
$myToken = $response['token'];


// GET CUSTOMER
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , 'Authorization: Bearer '.$myToken));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $wisoApiKey . ":" . $wisoSecretApiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.meinbuero.de/openapi/customer?'.http_build_query(
        array(
                'offset'        =>  0,
                'limit'         =>  10,
                'orderBy'       =>  'name',
                'desc'          =>  'false',
                'search'        =>  ''
        )));
    
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Now I need this curl commands (for testing) as a command which I can send via terminal.

TO get the toke I tried this successfully:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.meinbuero.de/openapi/auth/token" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"ownershipId\":\"XYZ\"}" -u WISO_API_KEY:WISO_SECRET_API_KEY
```

But than I would like to get the customers:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.meinbuero.de/openapi/customer?offset=0&search=&limit=20&orderBy=title&desc=true" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -u WISO_API_KEY:WISO_SECRET_API_KEY -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN"
```

I get the message:

```
Unauthorized%
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the space before the `WISO_SECRET_API_KEY` is not needed.

Comment: Just one simple question. Why don't you call that PHP script from CLI?

Comment: You know you can execute PHP scripts from CLI/terminal, right?

Comment: because the api provider means, that a issue, which I had, comes from my server. Now I would like to start a curl form a different machine, without php and via terminal to check this

Comment: the space before WISO_SECRET_API_KEY was my mistake in the post. I changed this

Comment: But the PHP version basically works fine, right?

Comment: no, I get an 500 server error with one curl request to this api

Comment: By definition, 5XX errors are the servers' mistake, not the clients'. :) Of course, only if error codes were appropriately implemented by the API provider.